# Get data in Y-Z dimension of 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D matrix with size is `120x256x256` where 120 is number of slices and 256x256 is size of each image slice. I want to extract the 3D matrix into 2D image (256x256). How to get the data of 3D matrix. I try to with matlab code:

```
Img_3D=zeros(120,256,256);
for numSlice=1:120
   Img2D=Img_3D(numSlice,:,:);
end
```

But it does not work. It return a matrix that size is `1x256x256`, instead of `256x256` matrix. How to fix my problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [**`squeeze`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) your resulting Matrix to get what you want.

```
Img_3D=zeros(120,256,256);

for numSlice = 120:-1:1   %// backwards for preallocation
   slices{numSlice } = squeeze( Img_3D(numSlice,:,:) );
end
```

basically the same can be achieved using `permute` as you suggested

```
for numSlice = 120:-1:1   %// backwards for preallocation
   slices{numSlice } = permute( Img_3D(numSlice,:,:),[2 3 1] );
end
```

performance-wise equal.

And after some timings it doesn't seem to matter if you `permute` in advance or not:

```
Img_3D = permute(Img_3D,[2 3 1]);
for numSlice = 120:-1:1   %// backwards for preallocation
   slices{numSlice } = Img_3D(numSlice,:,:);
end
```

Comment: How about Img_3D= permute(Img_3D,[2 3 1]); after that I will use Img2D=Img_3D(:,:,numSlice);

Comment: @user3051460 you can do it also, should provide the same result with the almost same perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly solve this problem using squeeze(), it is the most easy way of removing singleton dimensions. squeeze() detects the singleton dimension(s) and removes it (them) by calling reshape() accordingly. If speed is an issue, you could speed it up by using reshape() yourself, saving some computations:

```
Img_3D=reshape(1:120*256*256, [120,256,256]);

t0 = tic;
for j = 1:100
    for numSlice = 120:-1:1   %// backwards for preallocation
       slices_squeeze{numSlice } = squeeze( Img_3D(numSlice,:,:) );
    end
end
t_squeeze = toc(t0);

t0 = tic;
for j = 1:100
    for numSlice = 120:-1:1   %// backwards for preallocation
       slices_reshape{numSlice } = reshape(Img_3D(numSlice,:,:),[256, 256]);
    end
end
t_reshape = toc(t0);

fprintf('squeeze-solution: %5.3f seconds\n', t_squeeze);
fprintf('reshape-solution: %5.3f seconds\n', t_reshape);
```

The speedup is not too much though...

```
squeeze-solution: 5.654 seconds
reshape-solution: 4.790 seconds
```

Best, Nras.